# Group XML using xslt based on Header or Document Entry

Tags: xslt

How to group the XML using xlst for the below xml code.
Following are the input XML: I'm using this input xml in order to import into an ERP system.

```
 <row>
        <Ref>1</Ref>
        <Code>IT001</Code>
        <Qty>11</Qty>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Ref>1</Ref>
        <Code>IT002</Code>
        <Qty>21</Qty>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Ref>2</Ref>
        <Code>IT002</Code>
        <Qty>12</Qty>
    </row>
```

following are the Output or expected XML: ERP system generally accepts one line per document and it's siblings of document lines. Thus the following desired output is required.

```
<Document>
    <Ref>1</Ref><Lines>
        <Item>
            <Code>IT001</Code>
            <Qty>11</Qty>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Code>IT002</Code>
            <Qty>21</Qty>
        </Item>
    </Lines>
</Document>
<Document>
    <OrderRef>2</OrderRef>
    <Lines>
        <Item>
            <Code>IT002</Code>
            <Qty>12</Qty>
        </Item>
    </Lines>
</Document>
```

Comment: Please post your XSL even if not working. See [mcve].

Comment: [Please check my current XSL](https://pastebin.com/qiz5A8G3)

Comment: Please post all code (XML,XSLT, expected output) in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from a correction of your source XML:

There must be **only one** root element (I called it *Root*)
and inside it there can be multiple (e.g. *Document*) elements.

The template performing the transformation should match the
*Root* element.

As I see from your expected output, you want to group  *Document*
elements on *DocumentRef*, so in the script below there is
corresponding *xsl:for-each-group* instruction.

For each such group there should be *Document* output element
and inside it *Ref* element with the value of the current
grouping key.

Then there should be a *Lines* element and inside it, for each
member of the current group, there should be *Item* element
and inside it 2 child elements with required values from the
source element.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Document" group-by="DocumentRef">
        <Document>
          <Ref><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Ref>
          <Lines>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <Item>
                <ItemCode><xsl:value-of select="DocumentLines/ItemCode"/></ItemCode>
                <Qty><xsl:value-of select="DocumentLines/ItemQty"/></Qty>
              </Item>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Lines>
        </Document>      
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example, including corrected input, see http://xsltransform.net/eieE3PX

## XSLT 1.0 version

In **XSLT 1.0** it is also possible, using *Muenchian Grouping*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="row" use="OrderRef"/>

  <xsl:template match="Payload">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(
        key('groups', OrderRef)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <Document>
      <Ref><xsl:value-of select="OrderRef"/></Ref>
      <CardCode><xsl:value-of select="CustomerCode"/></CardCode>
      <Lines>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', OrderRef)">
          <Item>
            <ItemCode><xsl:value-of select="ItemCode"/></ItemCode>
            <Qty><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></Qty>
          </Item>  
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Lines>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The initial step is to create an `xsl:key`. Each key must have a `name` to
refer to it later. `match` defines which elements to include in this *key*
and `use` defines the grouping key.

Then look at:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(
  key('groups', OrderRef)[1])]"/>
```

It "calls an action" (in this case `xsl:apply-templates`) on
the first object in each group.

The rest of code from my initial solution has been moved to
a template matching *row*.

The initial part of it performs actions for the current group
(generate output *Document*, *Ref*, *CardCode* and *Lines*
elements).

The rest (`xsl:for-each`) performs actions for individual
members of the current group, generating *Item*, *ItemCode*
and *Qty* elements.

I updated your solution in *xsltransform*, so you can view
it on http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjW2/2

Note that I changed the XSLT engine to *Saxon 6.5.5*. You can also
switch it to *Xalan*, although then you loose indentation.

If this approach is new to you, maybe you should read a little about
*generate-id* and *Muenchian Grouping* itself. Even StackOverflow contains
a lot of posts about these issues.

Comment: Hi @Valdi_Bo , my application is not supporting XSL version 2.0 thus not supporting xsl:for-each-group. Is there a way to implement the same using XSL 1.0 version?

Comment: Hi @Valdi_Bo , modified the working copy in order to match my exact input xml. By the way, I used your xslt statement which works fine. But my application is not supporting xsl version 2.0 thus not supporting xsl:for-each-group. 

XSL working copy here. [http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjW2](http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjW2)